# Java rmi multi-module docker

Tags: spring, docker, rmi

I'm having a problem with my rmi java application which I wish to dockerize. The problem is that the application is a multi-module application with the following structure
[image]

I wish to dockerize the server, however if I try to do that by using `docker build -t server .`
it gives me the following error:

```
#12 1.504 [ERROR]
#12 1.504 [ERROR]   The project parent_group:server:0.1-SNAPSHOT (/root/pom.xml) has 1 error
#12 1.505 [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for parent_group:server:0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact parent_group:parent:pom:0.1-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 7, co
lumn 11 -> [Help 2]
#12 1.508 org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not find artifact parent_group:parent:pom:0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

My dockerfile for server:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11 AS builder


COPY ./src/ /root/src
COPY ./pom.xml /root/
COPY ./checkstyle.xml /root/
WORKDIR /root

RUN mvn -X clean package
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar target/parent-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar list
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar target/parent-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar extract
RUN ls -l /root

FROM openjdk:11.0.6-jre




COPY --from=builder /root/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder /root/snapshot-dependencies/ ./

RUN sleep 10
COPY --from=builder /root/spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=builder /root/application/ ./
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher","-XX:+UseContainerSupport -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRAMFraction=1 -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseSerialGC -Xss512k -XX:MaxRAM=72m"]
```